# Is this tensorial identity correct?

Tags: tensor-products

In our introductory course to QFT our teacher used this expression for the contraction of two completely antisymmetric tensors of rank 4:

$$ \epsilon^{\mu\nu\alpha\beta}\epsilon_{\mu\sigma\alpha\rho} = - 2(\delta^{\nu}\space_{\sigma}\delta^{\beta}\space_{\rho} - \delta^{\nu}\space_{\rho}\delta^{\beta}\space_{\sigma}).$$

I'm not sure this expression is correct; looking at [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2166371/how-do-i-compute-the-contraction-epsilon-abcd-epsilonab-rho-sigma) and considering the antisymmetric nature of the tensors, shouldn't it be

$$ \epsilon^{\mu\nu\alpha\beta}\epsilon_{\mu\sigma\alpha\rho} =  2(\delta^{\nu}\space_{\sigma}\delta^{\beta}\space_{\rho} - \delta^{\nu}\space_{\rho}\delta^{\beta}\space_{\sigma})$$

the right contraction?

Comment: Neither of them look right. Take a look at [the wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levi-Civita_symbol)
The identity you are looking for is the second-to-last formula, at the bottom of the page.

Comment: I edited the question, now I think one of them it’s correct; and looking at the relation you redirected me it seems that my teacher was right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\epsilon^{\mu\nu\alpha\beta}\epsilon_{\mu\sigma\alpha\rho} 
= \sqrt{g}\, e^{\mu\nu\alpha\beta}\frac{\operatorname{sgn}(g)}{\sqrt{g}}e_{\mu\sigma\alpha\rho}
= \operatorname{sgn}(g)\, \delta^{\mu\nu\alpha\beta}_{\mu\sigma\alpha\rho} = \operatorname{sgn}(g)\,
\begin{vmatrix}
\delta^\mu_\mu& \delta^\mu_\sigma& \delta^\mu_\alpha& \delta^\mu_\rho\\ 
\delta^\nu_\mu& \delta^\nu_\sigma& \delta^\nu_\alpha& \delta^\nu_\rho\\ 
\delta^\alpha_\mu& \delta^\alpha_\sigma& \delta^\alpha_\alpha& \delta^\alpha_\rho\\ 
\delta^\beta_\mu& \delta^\beta_\sigma& \delta^\beta_\alpha& \delta^\beta_\rho\\ 
\end{vmatrix}
$$

The determinant give:
$$
\delta^\mu_\mu
\begin{vmatrix}
\delta^\nu_\sigma& \delta^\nu_\alpha& \delta^\nu_\rho\\ 
\delta^\alpha_\sigma& \delta^\alpha_\alpha& \delta^\alpha_\rho\\ 
\delta^\beta_\sigma& \delta^\beta_\alpha& \delta^\beta_\rho\\ 
\end{vmatrix}
-
\delta^\mu_\sigma
\begin{vmatrix}
\delta^\nu_\mu&  \delta^\nu_\alpha& \delta^\nu_\rho\\ 
\delta^\alpha_\mu&  \delta^\alpha_\alpha& \delta^\alpha_\rho\\ 
\delta^\beta_\mu&  \delta^\beta_\alpha& \delta^\beta_\rho\\ 
\end{vmatrix}
+
\delta^\mu_\alpha
\begin{vmatrix}
\delta^\nu_\mu& \delta^\nu_\sigma& \delta^\nu_\rho\\ 
\delta^\alpha_\mu& \delta^\alpha_\sigma& \delta^\alpha_\rho\\ 
\delta^\beta_\mu& \delta^\beta_\sigma& \delta^\beta_\rho\\ 
\end{vmatrix}
-
\delta^\mu_\rho
\begin{vmatrix}
\delta^\nu_\mu& \delta^\nu_\sigma& \delta^\nu_\alpha\\ 
\delta^\alpha_\mu& \delta^\alpha_\sigma& \delta^\alpha_\alpha\\ 
\delta^\beta_\mu& \delta^\beta_\sigma& \delta^\beta_\alpha\\ 
\end{vmatrix}
$$
$$
\delta^\mu_\mu
\begin{vmatrix}
\delta^\nu_\sigma& \delta^\nu_\alpha& \delta^\nu_\rho\\ 
\delta^\alpha_\sigma& \delta^\alpha_\alpha& \delta^\alpha_\rho\\ 
\delta^\beta_\sigma& \delta^\beta_\alpha& \delta^\beta_\rho\\ 
\end{vmatrix}
-
\begin{vmatrix}
\delta^\nu_\sigma&  \delta^\nu_\alpha& \delta^\nu_\rho\\ 
\delta^\alpha_\sigma&  \delta^\alpha_\alpha& \delta^\alpha_\rho\\ 
\delta^\beta_\sigma&  \delta^\beta_\alpha& \delta^\beta_\rho\\ 
\end{vmatrix}
+
\begin{vmatrix}
\delta^\nu_\alpha& \delta^\nu_\sigma& \delta^\nu_\rho\\ 
\delta^\alpha_\alpha& \delta^\alpha_\sigma& \delta^\alpha_\rho\\ 
\delta^\beta_\alpha& \delta^\beta_\sigma& \delta^\beta_\rho\\ 
\end{vmatrix}
-
\begin{vmatrix}
\delta^\nu_\rho& \delta^\nu_\sigma& \delta^\nu_\alpha\\ 
\delta^\alpha_\rho& \delta^\alpha_\sigma& \delta^\alpha_\alpha\\ 
\delta^\beta_\rho& \delta^\beta_\sigma& \delta^\beta_\alpha\\ 
\end{vmatrix}
$$
$$
=
(\delta^\mu_\mu-3)
\begin{vmatrix}
\delta^\nu_\sigma& \delta^\nu_\alpha& \delta^\nu_\rho\\ 
\delta^\alpha_\sigma& \delta^\alpha_\alpha& \delta^\alpha_\rho\\ 
\delta^\beta_\sigma& \delta^\beta_\alpha& \delta^\beta_\rho\\ 
\end{vmatrix} 
= (\delta^\mu_\mu-3)(\delta^\alpha_\alpha-2)
(\delta^\nu_\sigma \delta^\beta_\rho-\delta^\nu_\rho \delta^\beta_\sigma)
$$

this give :
$$\operatorname{sgn}(g)\, 2(\delta^\nu_\sigma \delta^\beta_\rho-\delta^\nu_\rho \delta^\beta_\sigma)$$
where $g$ is the determinant of the metric and :
$$
\delta^\mu_\nu = 
\begin{bmatrix}
1&0&0&0\\ 
0&1&0&0\\ 
0&0&1&0\\ 
0&0&0&1\\ 
\end{bmatrix} 
$$

Thanks Jackozee Hakkiuz for the comment that helped me to understand the Minkowski case.

Comment: The problem is you are not using Minkowski metric in your first equal sign.

$$\epsilon^{\mu\nu\alpha\beta}\epsilon_{\mu\sigma\alpha\rho} =\delta^{\mu\nu\alpha\beta}_{\mu\sigma\alpha\rho}$$

In Minkowski metric we have

$$\epsilon^{\mu\nu\alpha\beta}\epsilon_{\mu\sigma\alpha\rho} = - \delta^{\mu\nu\alpha\beta}_{\mu\sigma\alpha\rho}$$

You can see this by requiring that
$$\epsilon_{abcd} = \eta_{ae}\eta_{bf}\eta_{cg}\eta_{dh}\epsilon^{efgh}$$
and recalling this identity for the determinant
$$\det(\eta)\varepsilon_{abcd} = \eta_{ae}\eta_{bf}\eta_{cg}\eta_{dh}\varepsilon^{efgh}$$

Comment: ...where the $\epsilon$ are the Levi-Civita *tensors* while the $\varepsilon$ are the Levi-Civita *symbols*.

This leads us to define

$$\epsilon_{abcd} = \sqrt{|g|}\varepsilon_{abcd}$$
and
$$\epsilon^{abcd} = \frac{-1}{\sqrt{|g|}}\varepsilon^{abcd}$$

Comment: Hum I thought that $\epsilon^\mu\nu\alpha\beta$ was $\sqrt{g} e^\mu\nu\alpha\beta$ and $\epsilon_\mu\nu\alpha\beta$ was $\frac{1}{\sqrt{g}} e^\mu\nu\alpha\beta$

Comment: That is true in the riemannian case. For the Lorentzian case you need to flip sign in order for 

$$\epsilon_{abcd} = \eta_{ae}\eta_{bf}\eta_{cg}\eta_{dh}\epsilon^{efgh}$$

to hold.
It even is in the bottom line of the [section in the wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levi-Civita_symbol#Levi-Civita_tensors).
You can do the calculation yourself, following my first two comments.

Comment: Thanks, I'll correct it

Answer (score 2):

It actually depends on the [signature of the metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_signature).

You see, the actual relation is

$$\epsilon^{abcd}\epsilon_{efgh} = \text{sgn}(g)\,\delta^{abcd}_{efgh}$$

Where $\text{sgn}(g)$ is the determinant of the metric with respect to an orthonormal basis.

So if you are using a Riemannian metric, $\text{sgn}(g) = 1$, and the second identity you wrote is valid. But if you are in spacetime the metric is Lorentzian, hence you get $\text{sgn}(g) = -1$, and what your teacher wrote applies.